# В качестве URL перенаправления подключенного приложения через facebook только htpps?

Tags: redirect, facebook

В качестве URL перенаправления подключенного приложения через facebook только htpps ?
Пытаюсь задать просто ip или доменное имя вида https://xx.xx.xx.xx.xip.io не разрешает.
При этом в google авторизации перенаправления https://xx.xx.xx.xx.xip.io  разрешает, работает у меня.
С 2018 года невозможно изменить переключатель "Требовать HTTPS" в положение не требовать.

Все теперь без доменного имени с https  никак?

P. S. мне это нужно для пет проекта в портфолио, а не для серьезного использования.

Answer (score 0):

Такие функции, как маркеры доступа и разрешения, делают вход через Facebook надежным и безопасным инструментом для людей и приложений. Однако веб-процессы OAuth или задайте список разрешенных URL для перенаправления. приложения так, чтобы они использовали только URL HTTPS.